# Is there positive proof that the Rambam did not accept Kabbalah?

Tags: rambam, mysticism-kabbalah, tractate-chagiga

I have heard many times that the Rambam's omission of mystical ideas is proof, or evidence, of his rejection thereof.  However, if one accepts the authenticity of Kabbalah as being a legitimate tradition sourced back to at least R' Shimon Bar Yochai, then that includes the fact that it was a secret tradition, as would be supported by the [Mishna in Chagiga 2:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%92%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%90) that the מעשה מרכבה should not even be taught directly to an individual.  From the way the Ramban introduces Kabbalistic ideas in his commentary on Chumash, it seems that he was not entirely comfortable to let the cat out of the bag.  Therefore, silence seems inconclusive.

Is there positive evidence of the Rambam's rejection of Kabbalah, by which I mean statements which seem to acknowledge it and dismiss it?

Comment: both maa3sa bareisheeth and markabo are science and not "kabbala" as brought down by rambam zl in mora nabucheem.

Comment: also he rejected sheeu3r qoma as a book of 3abodho zoro

Comment: Somewhat [related chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11595/2013/11/20).

Comment: Although this does not address the fundamental tenets of Kabbalah, the Vilna Gaon sharply criticized the Rambam's rejection or reinterpretation of ideas regarding witchcraft, demons, amulets, divine names, and kabbalistic formulations/incantations ([*Bei'ur HaGra* YD 179:13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5168)).

Comment: @yez http://www.chayas.com/AntiRAMBAM.pdf enjoy

Comment: Some relevant sources in the last two paragraphs [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16077&st=&pgnum=606&hilite=) - doesn't answer the question though. I was going to get around to asking the same question when I saw that, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob I didn't finish that article, but it doesn't seem too authoritative.  I am unfamiliar with a lot of his discussion, but the parts I am familiar with he doesn't present very evenhandedly. And his credentials are also interesting.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Does Rabbi Kook offer any evidence?

Comment: @yez he is top safaradi 7achom in america :)

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob I still don't see why that qualifies him to argue history with preeminent historians any more than being a safaradi 7achom would qualify him to talk about botany or biology.

Comment: __Comments removed.__ Please take discussions to [chat].

Comment: @YEZ  It's a excerpt from a book I haven't read, called "The Faith of Maimonides".  You can see it about halfway down the page here:  http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2010/12/rambams-mechanism-of-reward-and.html

Comment: https://f2h.io/jq76b26hss6d

Answer (score 9):

Menachem Kellner [wrote a book on the topic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906764158), where he builds on work by Moshe Idel. Kellner takes for granted that Rambam rejected (what was taught as) kabbalah of his day, and his book 'shows' how much of the Rambam's writings were aimed at presenting an alternative to kabbalah. You could read his book as indirectly proving that the Rambam rejected kabbalah, because if he's writing with an anti-kabbalah agenda he obviously rejected it. However, in my mind, Kellner's book still doesn't prove anything conclusively.

All in all, the scholarly consensus is that the Rambam rejected kabbalah, or what he knew of it, and not just because he writes in a teshuvah ([Blau ed. I:117](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1730&pgnum=215)) that the kabbalistic book [Shiur Komah](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%94_%28%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%29) is heretical. The Rambam's whole outlook doesn't seem to fit with many of the tenets of kabbalah, at least of what we know of it from that time. While you're right that these things were kept under wraps by those who knew them, the Rambam states in the introduction (and throughout) Moreh Nevuchim that in his book he is revealing the secrets of מעשה בראשית and מעשה מרכבה as he understands them, and they certainly don't look like kabbalah.

Of course, this is all kind of tenuous because we can't be sure how to read the kabbalistic works just because we have the texts. Maybe we're reading them incorrectly, as many authentic mekubalim (like R. Yaakov Hillel) of today will tell you that certain terms are codes for certain concepts, and that the mekubalim speak metaphorically, etc... This is especially so because later mekubalim actually did use the Moreh Nevuchim and picked up some of the Rambam's terminology here and there.

(For the sake of completeness, however, I should mention that there are two letters supposedly written by the Rambam which do in fact praise the kabbalah, though scholars have dismissed them as forgeries. One of them is quoted by the Migdal Oz to the first chapter of Hil. Yisodei HaTorah, where the Rambam is said to have discovered kabbalah later in life, and another well known one published in R. Shilat’s edition of the Rambam's letters, pg. 695. See there where he discusses the veracity of the letter)

Comment: The problem that I have is, the Gaonim also gave rational explanations which could be taken as alternatives to Kabbala, and yet there exist teshuvos where the Gaonim "hushed" people who espoused Kabbalistic views - didn't correct them, but hushed them.  That is why I want positive proof, not proof in abstentia.  Rejecting Shiur Komah is closer, but still not really conclusive.

Comment: Re Shiur Komah, that isn't conclusive because specific kabbalistic ideas in the book could have been problematic to him.  I don't know what it says in the book, or which parts he called heretical, so I can't really judge, but it's certainly incomplete.

Comment: @YEZ true, but the geonim never say that their explanations of aggada are to be considered 'maaseh beraishis' and 'maaseh merkava' (Truth is though that I don't think that's right about the geonim, if we're talking about rav sheriara and rav hai, but that's another topic)

Comment: @Matt There is a specific teshuva which I think is from R' Sherira about how kevutzas haderech works, in which he had given a very rational explanation, someone wrote him asking "doesn't it work like this" with a "kabbalistic" explanation, and he essentially responded "we don't talk about those things"

Comment: @Matt I don't have a link, but it's brought in Otzar HaGe'onim on maseches Sukka.

Comment: @Matt, do you know of any dating (what year it was written) of that Teshuva from the Rambam?

Comment: @Yishai rambam liked sheeu3r qoma in the beginning of his life, but as he learned philosophy and the sciences, he rejected it and said it is kafeero. it is also mentioned by rabbeinu abrohom ban ha rambam zl in his meel7omoth hashem that some rabbis were mistaken in taken it as actual fact and that it is kafeero

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, what is your source for that statement (that he liked it at the beginning of his life)? In the Teshuva quoted by Matt, he writes לא חשבתי מעולם שהוא מחיבורי החכמים ז"ל.

Comment: @Yishai In Shlomoh ben Yosef's translation of Rambam's opening to his commentary on Sanhedrin Ch. 10 (_Pereq Cheleq_), in the section on the seventh foundation, it says "ויכנס בזה שיעור קומה ועניינו" ( see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37945&pgnum=467), five lines before the end of the page). In Yosef Qafih's translation it doesn't appear, but in the footnotes he says that it was in the first edition of Rambam's manuscript, but was later erased from it. (See also [here](http://yediah.blogspot.com/2008/07/prophets-and-angels-ishim-and-keruvim.html), s.v. "Earlier I noted ...")

Comment: Your edit actually does address the question in a roundabout way - if those claims were correct, it would mean that up until then he had not heard of it, not just that he was being secret about it.

Comment: @YeZ I recently renewed my efforts to find this teshuvah that you mentioned about the Geonim refusing to speak about kabbalah and instead give alternative explanations, but I'm coming up short. Do you remember where you saw it? I don't think that it's in the Otzar HaGeonim to Sukkah, and I've looked through several studies of the Geonim's approach to aggadah without seeing even a passing reference to this idea

Comment: It should be noted (I think R. Dr. Twersky makes this point in Rabad of Posquieres) that the kabbalists insisted that kishuf had actual power whereas Rambam (following R. Saadya Gaon, et al.) insists that it is mere slight of hand.

Comment: @Yishai Apropos, Maimonides originally accepted Shiur Qomah as an authentic and legitimate Jewish treatise, but eventually rejected it as equivalent to idolatry.21 It may have been the Rambam himself who penned, in substitution for the laudatory original, the following closing lines to Shiur Qomah found in a medieval quotation: ‘

Comment: All these things are great abominations and blasphemies/cursed is he who believes it and cursed is he who composed it/by the numerical value of every letter in it/for the Lord is a true God/He has no image or measure/neither breadth nor length / as it says, ‘To whom then can you liken God etc. [What form does compare to Him?]’ (Isaiah 40, 18), ‘To whom then can you liken me, to whom can I be compared?’ (ibid., 40, 25).22

Comment: 21 ‘For only foreign gods have ‘stature’ [= qomah] (Maimonides Responsa, 117, ed.Blau, p. 201). See Lieberman, 1939, 12, 89–98; Lieberman apud Scholem, 1960, 124; Cohen, 1985, 230.  

ANTHROPOMORPHISM AND ITS ERADICATION by shamma friedman

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hDdPzVL.png http://i.imgur.com/Rl5mc50.png Moses Narboni‘s “Epistle on Shi‘ur Qomā” by alexander altmann

Comment: @Matt He might be referring to the teshuvah of R. Hai Gaon, #22 in Teshuvot Hageonim (Horowitz).

Comment: @Yishai (footnote 38) http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/9/13/index.htm#_ftnref_630