Where does the Rebbe write that Rambam was a mekubal
BH
I heard the Rebbi mi Lubavich (Rebbi) said Rambam was a mekubal. Where does he say this?

See p. 33, 34 here: https://derher.org/wp-content/uploads/Teves-5783-8.pdf

Not an answer because the OP asks particularly about the Lubavicher Rebbe זצ״ל referring to the Rambam as a "mekubal" (kabbalist) but see Rambam as Kabbalist: An Early Account by Dr Tamar Ron Marvin https://trmarvin.org/rambam-as-kabbalist-an-early-account/ and in particular the sources cited by the author in her footnote 1.

There are (completely unverified) reports of rambam believing in (Lurianic/Zohar) kabbalah for centuries, always by kabbalists who are seemingly uncomfortable with the idea of Rambam disagreeing with them, cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40669/759

I seem to remember the Rebbe mentioning in a sicha that there are some who have a tradition that Rambam was taught by a Mekubal later in life. But that aside, what is the definition of "Mekubal" here? Rambam discusses explicitly the beginning parts of Ma'aseh Merkava and Ma'aseh Bereshit in Mishneh Torah and says beyond that is restricted teaching. In Hilchot Talmud Torah he writes: וְדִבְרֵי קַבָּלָה בִּכְלַל תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב הֵן וּפֵרוּשָׁן בִּכְלַל תּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה. וְהָעִנְיָנִים הַנִּקְרָאִים פַּרְדֵּס בִּכְלַל הַגְּמָרָא הֵן.

There are many earlier sefarim referring to the Rambam as a kabbalist

https://www.orharambam.com/forum/e65a34e7/ykhsv-shl-hrmb-m-l-khkmt-hqblh

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15950&st=&pgnum=262

B"H
There are many sefarim that discuss the Rambam being a kabbalist. One source from the Luvavitcher Rebbe at the top of my head:

It is not surprising that the Rambam seeks to clarify an issue whose
source is in the Zohar, for the Rambam was a Kabbalist,20 and many of
the concepts stated in his works have their source in the Zohar or
other Kabbalistic texts.21

Those notes read:
20: See Sefer HaSichos Kayitz 5700, p. 41, note 27*.
21: See the notes of the Tzemach Tzedek to Moreh Nevuchim (at the conclusion of Sefer HaChakirah); the gloss of the Kessef Mishneh to Hilchos Mezuzah 5:4; the gloss of the Migdal Oz to Hilchos Teshuvah 5:5; Sefer Bar Yochai, sec. 6, excerpt 130; HaRambam VehaZohar by Rav Margolies. See also the gloss of the Tzafnas Paneach to Hilchos Avodas Kochavim 12:6, which explains that at least four [the standard texts of the Mishneh Torah state 40] hairs must remain at each corner of the head, because “it is explained in Kabalistic texts that there are four hairs at the corners [of the spiritual realm] of Adam Kadmon. ” See the text Mafteach HaOlamos.
